# Portrait video with black borders gets cropped / stretched

Tags: ffmpeg, crop, stretch, portrait

So i have a source which is 540x720 if it matters. It was processed with a deshaker, and because of that there are occasional black borders, several pixels wide.

What happens is after encoding these black areas get filled by stretching the actual image, or maybe that's called cropping in ffmpeg terms. Anyway, image gets stretched, the width of the video stays 540. It seems to not happen with top/bottom fields, only the sides.

I'd very much like to disable that but I don't know what exactly causes this.
My command line is

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vf "colormatrix=bt601:bt709" -c:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 17 output.mkv
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** I noticed that the video is stretched even at moments when there is no borders, strange. It's like the image just became wider by 4-5 pixels for no apparent reason. Though I suspect, those black borders have something to do with it.

The right-hand black border got filled (covered) completely throughout the whole video, I guess that's what this stretch is.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer. We don't do the "solved" thing you know from forums - we have a dedicated "accepted answer" feature.

Comment: Yeah, big "thanks" to anyone who deleted the edits with solution information. In that case you could have posted the answer yourself, you know.

Comment: Had I posted it myself, I'd be getting the reputation points you deserve.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with VLC player (under Windows), the solution is to choose a video output module different from Automatic or Direct3D9. Preferably Direct3D11 (plus, choose Direct3D11 acceleration in Input/Codecs tab).